# reduce a nested vector to another one in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, clojure, reduce

What is an idiomatic way of handling such stuff in Clojure?

I have:

```
(def data1
    [1 [2 3]])

(def data2
    [1 [[2 [3 [4]]]
        [22 33]]])
```

I want to get:

```
[1 2 3]
```

and

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 22 33]]
```

respectively. The nested levels of inner vectors may be of different lengths.

I cannot wrap my head around the nature of such inputs and looking for help. Basically a function should map an input (which is a vector) to an output (vector, also) which, in essence, is a vector of all the "routes" from its head to the innermost elements. This is a vague explanation, will be grateful for a better one.

Comment: Is the input always a vector of length 2? The second elements in your examples have a different structure, one is vector of numbers, the other is a vector of vectors. What is the interpretation of each part of the structure?

Comment: @Lee, no the input is not always a vector of length 2. in its trivial form it may be just [1] which should result in [[1]]. In other words the input has either 1 or 2 elements (where the 2nd element is a vector or a number). It may be helpful to treat the input as a tree where each vector is a branch.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head: this looks like a depth-first search to me.  [`tree-seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq) is the idiomatic way to walk a data structure in the way you're looking for, but I'm not clear on what output you're looking for.  

For example, what output would you want from this?

`(def data3
    [1 [[2 [3 [4]]]
        [22 33] 44]])`

Comment: @Conan, it should be ```[[1 2 3 4] [1 22 33] [1 44]]```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn transform [[f & r]]
(let [rr (apply concat r)]
  (if (= (flatten rr) rr) 
    (vec (cons f rr))
    (mapv #(if (vector? %) 
            (vec (cons f (flatten %)))
            [f %])
         rr))))
```

; Test Cases

```
(transform [1 [2 3]]) => [1 2 3]
(transform [1 [[2 [3 [4]]] [22 33]]]) => [[1 2 3 4] [1 22 33]]
(transform [1 [[2 [3 [4]]] [22 33] 44]]) => [[1 2 3 4] [1 22 33] [1 44]
(transform [1]) => [1]
(transform [1 [2]]) => [1 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn transform [v]
  (let [[x & [xs]] v]
    (loop [r xs
           res []]
      (cond
        (empty? r) res
        (vector? (first r)) (recur (rest r)
                                   (conj res
                                         (into
                                          (conj [] x)
                                          (flatten (first r)))))
        :else (into (conj res x) r)))))

(def data1
  [1 [2 3]])

(def data2
  [1 [[2 [3 [4]]]
      [22 33]]])

(def data3
  [1 [[20 25 [30 [40 [50]]]]
      [2 3 [4 5 [6 7 [8 9]]]]
      [[60] 70 [80 [90 100 [110 120 130 [140 150]]]]]]])

; user=> (transform data1)
; [1 2 3]
; user=> (transform data2)
; [[1 2 3 4] [1 22 33]]
; user=> (transform data3)
; [[1 20 25 30 40 50] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [1 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives wrong output for input ```[1]```. it should be ```[1]```, not ```[]```. For input ```[[1 [2]]]``` it also gives wrong output ```[]``` instead of ```[1 2]```.

Comment: @varnie What is your vector structure? I'm a little confused.